# Unit testing AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I need to write a unit test in Jasmine for the following bit of code.  What is happening is it's a simple bootstap-ui directive that is repeating though the tabs scope to create tabs on the page.

My question here is really what do I need to test?

HTML

```
<tabset type="pills" class="profile-content">
  <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}"  active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
  <h1>{{tab.title}}</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="item in sections">
      <p>{{item[tab.title]}}</p>
    </div>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

JavaScript

```
 medSelectorProfile.controller('ProfileController', [
        '$scope',
        '$routeParams',
        'localRestangular',
        '$http',
        function($scope, $routeParams, Restangular, $http) {

          Restangular.all('profile/universities/' + ($routeParams.school).toLowerCase() + '.json').getList().then(function(data) {
            $scope.schooldata = data;
            $scope.sections= data[0].sections;
            $scope.name = data[0].name;
            $scope.qualification = data[0].qualification;

          });

          $scope.tabs = [
            { title:'Grades', content: [] , active:true},
            { title:'Entrance exam', content:[]},
            { title:'Admissions policy', content:[]},
            { title:'Interviews', content:[]},
            { title:'Course info', content:[]},
            { title:'Fees', content:[]},
            { title:'Student life', content:[]},
            { title:'Teaching style', content:[]}
          ];

        }
        ]);//ProfileController
```

Comment: You need to stub of the `getList()` service and then test for all the `$scope` variables in the promise.

Comment: Perhaps posting what you have for your test spec so far will allow us to provide more suggestions. At a high level as dcodesmith said you will need to create a mock of your `getList` method. Then assert that is returns the values expected when resolving your promise. Additionally you could assert that `scope.tabs` contains the data expected.